# Haskell: Malformed instance

Tags: haskell

I have problem for realisation of next in Haskell:

Type class:

```
class CArgumentableAttr a where
    expressArgumentAttr :: a -> (WidgetUI -> UI WidgetUI)

instance CArgumentableAttr (WidgetUI -> UI WidgetUI) where expressArgumentAttr a = a
```

and realisation:

```
instance CArgumentableAttr (CSizeable b) => ((b, b, b, b) -> UI_StartingPoint -> WidgetUI -> UI WidgetUI) where expressArgumentAttr a = a (0, 0, 100, 50) UI_LT 
instance CArgumentableAttr (UI_StartingPoint -> WidgetUI -> UI WidgetUI) where expressArgumentAttr a = aUI_LT
```

here:

```
class Show a => CSizeable a where
    showSize :: a -> String
instance CSizeable Int where
    showSize a = (show a) ++ "px"
instance CSizeable String where
    showSize a = if '%' `elem` a then a else (a ++ "%")
```

It use for:

```
bounds :: CSizeable a => (a, a, a, a) -> UI_StartingPoint -> WidgetUI -> UI WidgetUI
bounds (x, y, width, height) startingPoint widget =
    case startingPoint of 
        UI_LT -> applyStyleToWidget widget ("left:"  ++ (showSize x) ++ ";top:" ...
```

When compiling get the following error:
Malformed instance: CArgumentableAttr (CSizeable b) =>                      ((b, b, b, b) -> UI_StartingPoint -> WidgetUI -> UI WidgetUI)

What can be done in this?
Thank you!

Comment: The error message usually contains the extension you need to activate. However, the constraint on `b` should come first, e.g. `instance CSizeable b => CArgumentableAttr`. This usually needs `-XFlexibleInstances`

Comment: I use `FlexibleInstances`

Comment: If use `XFlexibleInstances` then `........b9416b003 --enable-tests --enable-benchmarks Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1`

Comment: `setup-Simple-Cabal-1.22.5.0-ghc-7.10.3: The package Lizard-0.1.0.0 requires the following language extensions which are not supported by ghc-7.10.3: XFlexibleInstances`

Comment: Don't add additional information in comments, instead [edit] your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think @Toxaris identified the issue, but I wanted propose some potential adjustments that may make things easier for you.

A few red flags for me are:

1. There are `CSizeable` instances for both `Int` and `String` - this of course isn't *wrong* in any way taken in isolation
2. The `CSizeable Int` instance always assumes pixels which prevents you from ever being able to, for example, numerically represent a percentage
3. There is "parsing/checking" inside the `CSizeable String` instance
4. There are "unit-less" numbers in the `CArgumentableAttr` instance

My thought is that perhaps `CSizeable` would be better as a plain data type instead of a class, or that you would have newtype wrappers instead of instances for `Int` and `String`.

As a data type:

```
data Size = Pixels Int | Percent Double | Literal String
instance Show Size where
  show (Pixels x) = show x ++ "px"
  show (Percent x) = show x ++ "%"
  show (Literal x) = x

instance CArgumentableAttr ((Size,Size,Size,Size) -> UI_StartingPoint -> WidgetUI -> UI WidgetUI) where expressArgumentAttr a = a (Pixels 0, Pixels 0, Pixels 100, Pixels 50) UI_LT
instance CArgumentableAttr (UI_StartingPoint -> WidgetUI -> UI WidgetUI) where expressArgumentAttr a = a UI_LT

bounds :: (Size,Size,Size,Size) -> UI_StartingPoint -> WidgetUI -> UI WidgetUI
bounds (x,y,width,height) startingPoint widget =
  case startingPoint of
    UI_LT -> applyStyleToWidget widget ("left:"  ++ show x ++ ";top:" ...
```

The newtype wrappers could look something like this:

```
newtype Pixels = Pixels Int
newtype Percent = Percent Double
newtype Literal = Literal String

instance CSizeable Pixels where showSize (Pixels x) = show x ++ "px"
instance CSizeable Percent where showSize (Percent x) = show x ++ "%"
instance CSizeable Literal where showSize (Literal x) = x
```

Answer (score 3):

You use

```
instance CArgumentableAttr (CSizeable b) => ... where ...
```

but I think you want

```
instance (CSizeable b) => CArgumentableAttr ... where ...
```

instead.

Comment: In this case `code` Could not deduce (Num b) arising from the literal ‘0’
    from the context (CSizeable b)
      bound by the instance declaration
      at src/WebUI/Widgets/UIWidget.hs:642:10-105
    Possible fix:
      add (Num b) to the context of the instance declaration
    In the expression: 0
    In the first argument of ‘a’, namely ‘(0, 0, 100, 50)’
    In the expression: a (0, 0, 100, 50) UI_LT

Comment: @QSpider You would need to add a `Num b` constraint: `instance (Num b,CSizeable b) => CArgumentableAttr`. The implementation of the `Num` typeclass provides the logic for interpreting integer literals as a given type. This could be problematic since you have a `String` instance, so you would probably want to extend the `CSizeable` typeclass to support instantiation of literals rather than implementing `Num String`.